# How do I use standard deviation with a comparison operator?

Tags: pine-script

Whenever I try to use standard deviation with a comparison operator, I get this error:

> Cannot call 'operator >' with 'expr1'=series[bool]. The argument
> should be of type: float

Example script

```
//@version=4
study("script")
length = 10
size = open-close
average_size = sma(size,length)
dev = stdev(size,length)
cond = size > average_size + dev
bgcolor(cond?color.blue:na)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The script you've attached compiles and works fine on my end. Please re-check that you've attached the right code

Comment: You're right. It turns out I defined one of my variables with a variable that wasn't a float, which caused the error.